# SNS - subscribing to a topic does not need to be confirmed for application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

SNS newbie here.

Through the AWS console, I've created a topic and created a platform application.

In my iOS application's app delegate, I create an endpoint for this client and then ask sns to subscribe this client to the topic by providing the topic's ARN.

The whole process seems to work fine, but my concern is about the confirmation of the subscription: could someone confirm (no pun intended) that for applications, no confirmations are needed when an endpoint subscribes to a topic ?

A link to an official AWS page would be great (couldn't find any)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some subscriptions require confirmation, such as email and HTTP(S).  Mobile push is significantly different.

> Q: Does enabling push notifications require any special confirmations with SNS Mobile Push?
>
> No, they do not. End-users opt-in to receive push notifications when they first run an app, whether or not SNS delivers the push notifications.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/